# Help me understand this algorithm (simple)

Tags: c++, algorithm, queue

I have just made a queue class and I now have to use it to do this.

Write a c++ program to generate all strings using A,B,and C as the letters.

The strings must be generated in the following order:
A
B
C
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC
AAA
AAB
AAC
ABA
ABB
ABC
ACA
ACB
ACC
etc.

It's supposed to do this until my queue overflows.

Now, I simply don't understand the algorithm the teacher suggested using, which is this.

**Start with A and B and C in the queue.
“Remove it Display it then Add Add  Add ”**

The add add add thing throws me off, how does it accomplish getting these letters in this particular order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let our behavior be:

```
For any token X, add XA, XB, and XC to the queue.
```

Our flow will be something like:

```
Start with a Queue
A B C

Pop (and display) off A
B C

Behave on token: "A"
  add AA
  add AB
  add AC
B C AA AB AC

Pop (and display) off B
C AA AB AC
  add BA
  add BB
  add BC
C AA AB AC BA BB BC
```

If we pretend our function is

```
main() {
    Queue q;
    q.add("A");
    q.add("B");
    q.add("C");

    while(true) {
        process(q.pop());
    }
}

process(String x, Queue q) {
    display x;
    q.add(x + "A");
    q.add(x + "B");
    q.add(x + "C");
}
```

Get it now?

Comment: Well the queue uses a char array so I understand what you're saying but I'm not sure how I could implement that

Comment: @Tyler Keep a "head" and "tail" position counter. When you "pop" take `myArray[head];` as what you pop, and then go `head++;` to denote that you're moving past it. When you add to the queue, go `myArray[tail] = whatImAdding;` to add it, and `tail++` to denote that it has grown. This will overflow when `tail` tries to access something not part of your array.

Answer (score 7):

I think your teacher meant "Add A, Add B, Add C".

Suppose you have A, B and C in the queue. You pop the first one off the queue and print it. This should print A. Then you add an A to that. This gives you AA, which you push back into the queue. You also add a B and add a C to the string you popped last (giving you AB and AC) and push them back into the queue as well. Now your queue contains [B,C,AA,AB,AC]. Next you will pop B and do the same sequence of operations on that as well, and so on until you run out of space in your stack.

Answer (score 0):

A B C

prints A
new queue state
B C A A A

prints B
new queue state
C A A A B B B

prints C
new queue state
A A A B B B C C C

prints A
new queue state
A A B B B C C C A A A

prints A
new queue state
A B B B C C C A A A A A A

prints A
new queue state
B B B C C C A A A A A A A A A

This was my first interpretation of the cycle, but i must be getting it wrong, because i go from 1 repeat to 3 right away.

Update: definitely read the initial problem wrong after seeing the other responses.