# Using a capacity-constrained queue to list off strings in order?

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, queue, sequence

My professor made us write single `char` queue (no templates, just char), which I did without too much trouble.  Now I have use it to write a driver (main()) that will print out every combination of the sequence ABC.

The strings have to be generated in the following order:

```
A
B
C
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC
AAA
AAB
AAC
ABA
ABB
ABC
ACA
ACB
ACC
etc.
```

The MAX_SIZE = 10 for the queue, so it's supposed to throw overflow exception after about 25 strings.

here's the hint:

```
Start with A and B and C in the queue.
“Remove it Display it then Add Add  Add ”
```

Which kinda makes sense but I don't get how to make the main control structure transition up a character length everytime you know (like once it does all single characters move to double, then to triple, etc).

Comment: +1 This is a really interesting puzzle.  Even if this isn't quite what your prof intended, this is still really cool.

Comment: Can we use multiple queues?  What are the constraints on memory/data-structure usage?

Comment: Yea there's leeway so I assume multiple queues is okay.   I was hoping it might be something simple like an exponent formula or modulus or something but I'm stumped ~_~

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. Simple enough.

```
Queue q;

q.enqueue('A');
q.enqueue('\n');
q.enqueue('B');
q.enqueue('\n');
q.enqueue('C');
q.enqueue('\n');

for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    size_t len = 0;
    char str[256];
    char c;

    while ((c = q.dequeue()) != '\n')
        str[len++] = c;

    str[len] = '\0';

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        q.enqueue(str[j]);

    q.enqueue('A');
    q.enqueue('\n');

    for (size_t j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        q.enqueue(str[j]);

    q.enqueue('B');
    q.enqueue('\n');

    for (size_t j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        q.enqueue(str[j]);

    q.enqueue('C');
    q.enqueue('\n');
}
```

Comment: I think that this exceeds the limit of 10 characters inside the queue very quickly.  After one iteration it holds AnBnCn, which is six characters.  After that it holds BnAnAnBnCn, which is ten characters.  Can you do this without overflowing the capacity?

Comment: Well, it's possible to do this without the queue entirely. But if we need to use it to store all the permutations it will get big.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the question here is how to do this with just the queue.  I agree that the other generation methods are certainly worth looking into, though.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, let's note that if you have a queue of strings, this is not particularly difficult.  The general algorithm is a breadth-first search of the graph of strings:

1. Create an empty queue Q.
2. Insert the empty string into Q.
3. Loop until done (your definition of done):

   1. Dequeue the head of Q, call it w.
   2. Print w.
   3. Insert wA, wB, and wC into Q.

The catch in your problem is that you can't insert these strings into the queue without very rapidly exhausting all the free space.  However, if you are allowed to use multiple queues, you can chain the queues together to form one much larger queue.  For example, suppose you have two queues of capacity 3 each and want to make a queue of capacity 6.  To do this, label the queues as the "left queue" and the "right queue."  By default, you insert into the right queue, as shown here:

```
  Left            Right
  [ ] [ ] [ ]     [ ] [ ] [ ]         Enqueue A
  [ ] [ ] [ ]     [ ] [ ] [A]         Enqueue B
  [ ] [ ] [ ]     [ ] [A] [B]         Enqueue C
  [ ] [ ] [ ]     [A] [B] [C]
```

Now, suppose that you run out of space in the right queue.  In that case, dequeue an element from the right queue (it will be the oldest element in the combined queues), then enqueue it into the left queue:

```
  Left            Right
  [ ] [ ] [ ]     [A] [B] [C]         Enqueue D
  [ ] [ ] [A]     [B] [C] [D]         Enqueue E
  [ ] [A] [B]     [C] [D] [E]         Enqueue F
  [A] [B] [C]     [D] [E] [F]
```

Now, to do a dequeue operation, do the following.  First, if the left queue is nonempty, dequeue from it; that gives you back the oldest element in the bunch.  Otherwise, if the right queue is nonempty, dequeue from that one instead.  For example, here are some enqueues and dequeues:

```
  Left            Right
  [A] [B] [C]     [D] [E] [F]         Dequeue (yields A)
  [B] [C] [ ]     [D] [E] [F]         Dequeue (yields B)
  [C] [ ] [ ]     [D] [E] [F]         Dequeue (yields C)
  [ ] [ ] [ ]     [D] [E] [F]         Dequeue (yields D)
  [ ] [ ] [ ]     [ ] [E] [F]         Enqueue G
  [ ] [ ] [ ]     [E] [F] [G]         Enqueue H
  [ ] [ ] [E]     [F] [G] [H]         Dequeue (yields E)
```

You can generalize this technique by splicing multiple queues together into a long chain.  Using this, you can take your small queue, which only holds 10 characters, and form a much bigger queue, perhaps one with capacity 100 or 1000.

So how does this help out?  Well, using the chained queues, you can simulate a queue of strings!  To insert the string w, just insert the characters of w followed by some marker (say, $) into your queue.  For example:

```
 Long Queue Contents       Operation
 $                         Dequeue once to get $, insert A, B, C
 A$B$C$                    Dequeue twice to get A$, insert AA, AB, AC
 B$C$AA$AB$AC$             Dequeue twice to get B$, insert BA, BB, BC
 C$AA$AB$AC$BA$BB$BC$
```

etc.  Using this combination of smaller queues to simulate a bigger queue that simulates a queue of strings (woohoo!), you can solve the problem using the initial algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, this is exactly my answer only that you use many queues as one, of which I don't see the point. This is no better than increasing MAX_SIZE. If this is the best solution it is a very strange assignment.

Comment: I found a question literally the same as mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437766/help-me-understand-this-algorithm-simple

Comment: The accepted answer in that link is a queue of strings, not char. Is this what you have?

Comment: Literally same question down to the exact text.  The professor gave the queue.h file and it's a typedef char only so it must be wrong if using strings..

Comment: @rasmus- I was trying to preserve the basic BFS structure of the normal solution using the fact that the queue is bounded.  I don't at all think this is the best solution, but it was a cool thought experiment to see how to simulate a large queue from several smaller ones.  Also, how is this exactly your answer?  I don't see the connection, but I'm really interested if there's a clever transformation from one to the other.

Comment: @rasmus- Whoops!  I didn't realize that you had two answers.  Never mind... :-)

Comment: @user1139252- What class is asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, here is one using integer calculations only.

```
size_t len = 1;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    size_t x = 0;
    bool max = false;

    do {
        max = true;
        size_t y = x;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            char c = 'A' + (y%3);
            y /= 3;
            if (c != 'C')
                max = false;
            std::cout << c;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        x++;
    } while (!max);
    ++len;
}
```